# Stream Audio from Android to Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

I have a music player in Android, which uses android.media.MediaPlayer to play music from the SD card.

I would like to add the ability to cast the music to a Chromecast device.

I have played around with the democastplayer demo app. Specifically I tried to get the MediaRouteSelector to work with a '[live audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaControlIntent.html#CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)' route, but the 'cast' action button didn't show (suggesting live audio is not supported perhaps?).  I also tried a few other things, but had no luck getting democastplayer to send MP3 audio to Chromecast.

Is streaming/sending local SD MP3 files to Chromecast even possible?  If so, are there any sample apps or open source projects I can refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add/write a small web server to your android application so it can serve the local media. Then have your sender application send the url of the media (that your local server is serving) to chromecast so it can play the music directly served from your phone.

Comment: btw, https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd seems like a small webserver that could be useful to accomplish what you want

Comment: Note that this needs to be done carefully. Opening server ports on a mobile device is risky, insofar as things *other* than the Chromecast can also hit that server while it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Possible to stream your MP3 files by sending file url to chromecast device you can be using remote media player to load the media file. Refer this sample https://github.com/ovingalafsal/ChromeCastSampleApp  it might be helpful